# Getting information from an array when a form field is left empty in php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form field (`id="rate" name="rate"`) that the user is required to enter a value for. But if the user leaves it empty the value is taken from an array in `costs.php`. I have written this code but it does not seem to work; The `$total` variable is important to me.

```
<?php 
   $total = $form->data['rate'];
   if($value){
     echo $form->data['rate'];
   } else if($value === false){
     echo $costs['usd_ia'];
   } 
?>
```

Comment: Is `$value` supposed to be `$total`? And what do you mean by "important to you"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you should be changing that `else if` into an unconditional `else`, and using $total instead of $value.

```
<?php

$total = $form->data['rate'];
if ($total) {
   echo $form->data['rate'];
} else {
   echo $costs['usd_ia'];
}
```

However, note that this can be problematic. If the user enters (say) a value of `0`, that'll cause `if ($total)` to evaluate to FALSE, so if a 0-value is valid for your form, then you'll have to use some more complicated logic.